# EF Core Generic Repository error con metodo GetById

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Tengo un generic repository para mi crud en netcore, pero tengo un problema con uno de los metodos.

El metodo es GetById

```
        public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
    }
```

Y en la parte `(t => t.Id == id)`

Hay un error

> 'TEntity' no contiene una definición para 'Id' ni se encuentra ningún
>   método de extensión 'Id' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo
>   'TEntity' (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de
>   ensamblado?)

Este seria el header de mi GenericRepository

```
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DataContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DataContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa por que en metodo GetById recibe un parametro de tipo Generico, por tal motivo no contiene una propiedad Id, lo que tienes que hacer es en tu metodo  GetById reemplaza tu consulta por

```
return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(Id);
```